# jboss 5 to jboss 7 jms

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I am running jboss5 and jboss 7 in same machine, so I changed port nos(jboss5-4040 and jboss7-8080). I need to send a message from jboss 5 to jboss 7. I read an article, state that, have to use JMS bridge.

```
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/BridgeJMSMessagesFromAS5ToAS7
```

I created a queue in jboss 5 and sent messages to the queue by standalone program.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class sender {
    String url_;
    String name_;
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session = null;
    Queue queue = null;

    public sender(String url, String name) throws JMSException,
            NamingException {

        url_ = url;
        name_ = name;

        this.initializeSender();
    }

    private void initializeSender() throws JMSException, NamingException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");

        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");

        Context context = new InitialContext(props);

        ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context
                .lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");

        conn = cf.createConnection();

        session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        queue = (Queue) context.lookup(name_);

        conn.start();

    }

    public void send(String text) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        // Send a text msg
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(text);
        producer.send(tm);
        producer.close();
    }

    public void disconnect() throws JMSException {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.stop();
        }

        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    public String getTopicName() {
        return name_;
    }

    public String getTopicURL() {
        return url_;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        sender sender = new sender("remote://localhost:4447", "BalaQueue");

        sender.send("My Message");
        sender.disconnect();


    }

}
```

and I created a queue in jboss 7 and sent messages to the queue by standalone program.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class QSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QSender().send();
    }

    public void send() {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        try {
            // Strings for JNDI names
            String factoryName = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
            String queueName = "jms/queue/ram";
            // Create an initial context.
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ramguest");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props);

            QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context
                    .lookup(factoryName);
            Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(queueName);
            context.close();
            // Create JMS objects
            QueueConnection connection = factory.createQueueConnection(
                    "ramguest", "password");
            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);

            System.out.println("Enter message to send or 'quit' to quit.");
            String messageText = null;
            while (true) {
                messageText = reader.readLine();
                if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(messageText)) {
                    break;
                }
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(messageText);
                sender.send(message);
            }
            // Exit
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("Exiting...");
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and my bridge file(jboss-service.xml)

```
<server>    
    <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>    <!-- AS7 JMS Provider -->    
    <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.jndi.JMSProviderLoader" name="jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJBossMQProvider">     <attribute name="ProviderName">RemoteXAConnectionFactory</attribute>       
        <attribute name="ProviderAdapterClass">org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter</attribute>
        <attribute name="FactoryRef">jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</attribute>
        <attribute name="QueueFactoryRef">jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</attribute>
        <attribute name="TopicFactoryRef">jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</attribute>
        <attribute name="Properties">         java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory  

            java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
            java.naming.security.principal=ramguest 
            java.naming.security.credentials=password 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>    
    <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.BridgeService" name="jboss.jms:service=Bridge,name=LegayBridgeSend" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Bridge-xmbean.xml">            
        <depends optional-attribute-name="SourceProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=JMSProvider</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="TargetProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJBossMQProvider</depends>
        <attribute name="SourceDestinationLookup">BalaQueue</attribute>  
        <attribute name="TargetDestinationLookup">java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/ram</attribute>
        <attribute name="QualityOfServiceMode">1</attribute>
        <attribute name="MaxBatchSize">1</attribute>
        <attribute name="MaxBatchTime">-1</attribute>
        <attribute name="FailureRetryInterval">10000</attribute>
        <attribute name="MaxRetries">-1</attribute>
        <attribute name="AddMessageIDInHeader">false</attribute>    
        <attribute name="TargetUsername">ramguest</attribute>
        <attribute name="TargetPassword">password</attribute>   
    </mbean> 
</server>
```

When I start jboss5 I am getting exception

```
WARN  [Bridge] jboss.jms:name=LegayBridgeSend,service=Bridge Failed to set up connections
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1678)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1795)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.JNDIFactorySupport.createObject(JNDIFactorySupport.java:66)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.JNDIDestinationFactory.createDestination(JNDIDestinationFactory.java:45)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.Bridge.setupJMSObjects(Bridge.java:953)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.Bridge.setupJMSObjectsWithRetry(Bridge.java:1223)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.Bridge.access$1600(Bridge.java:68)
        at org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.Bridge$FailureHandler.run(Bridge.java:1569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:725)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1647)
```

Can anybody guide me please...

Comment: A lot easier is to use REST web services. RestEeasy's implementation is as its name suggests easy. There are several examples how to establish a rest service and how to call it in jBoss 7 quickstarter set of projects. Believe it's not much harder doing the same on the side of jBoss 5.

Comment: I should do this with JMS only as per requirements..

Comment: add outgoing and incoming queues at both servers and have a sender rest client read messages from the outgoing queue posting them to the other server's web service which would add the messages to its incoming queue and vice-versa. this will recreate the jms bridge, yet keeping two servers decoupled with humanly readable transportation mechanism

Comment: in jboss-service.xml, I have added SourceDestinationLookup and TargetDestinationLookup. These are incoming and outgoing queues.But now the above error has been solved and throwing some new error "javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.xnio.XnioProvider: Provider org.xnio.nio.NioXnioProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.nio.NioXnioProvider]"  
org.xnio.nio.NioXnioProvider class is also available in classpath

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS AS 7 doesn't support JNP , Use jboss remoting

```
<attribute name="Properties">
      java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory  
      java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
      java.naming.security.principal=ramguest 
      java.naming.security.credentials=password 
</attribute>
```

Change

```
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
```

to

```
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
```